# Environment variabels unaccessible from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, cloud9-ide

I am building a rails application where I have some initial configuration files that use environment variables, and I'm using the cloud9 ide. I am setting the environment variables using `export`, yet when the server is running rails tells me the parameter whose value is supposed to be one of the environment variables is missing, and when I used the debugger, `ENV["VAR_NAME"]` returns nothing. Any ideas why? When I run `echo $VAR_NAME` in bash, it returns the correct value.

EDIT: When I run `console --sandbox`, the environment variables are also available. Only in the controller are they not available.

Comment: If you use `export`, the environment variable ends up only being applied to the terminal *tab* in which you ran the command (don't ask me why). You should apply environment variables to `/etc/environment` if you want system-wide environment variables:

`vim /etc/environment`

Make a change, i.e. `RAILS_ENV=development` (one variable per line). Save the file, reload your terminals (you may need to restart your workspace entirely).

 If you want user-specific environment variables (unlikely), use `~/.profile`.

Comment: `/etc/environment` is readonly, and `~/.profile` makes no difference to rails, i still can't access the environment variables.
EDIT: I restarted my workspace. Still now working.

Comment: how are you running the rails app? Via runner or terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding `export VAR_NAME=var_value` in `.bashrc`.